# iOS DropboxSDK, get remote subdirectories and contents

Tags: objective-c, ios, asynchronous, dropbox

I have a remote directory with several subdirectories and files in them on Dropbox.

**remote side:**

```
-Mobile Profiles *(root)*
-- Custom Profiles
--- Profile1
--- Profile2
--- Profile3
```

Uploading the files and directories / and subdirectories with files is not a problem. I am having a brain fart when it comes to getting the subdirectories and their contents from dropbox to the device.

### put

```
-(void)backupCustomProfiles {
    for ( NSString *file in [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:MP_CUSTOM error:&error] ) {
        [self.restClient uploadFile:file toPath:@"/Mobile Profiles/Custom Profiles/" fromPath:EasyStrings(MP_CUSTOM,file)];
    }
}
```

### get

```
-(void)restoreCustomProfiles {
    for ( ) {
        /* ? */
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to iterate through the subdirectories on the remote side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First load the directory metadata, then load the files that it references.

To limit the number of parallel fetches, use a NSOperationQueue for all of the loadMetadata and loadFile calls to limit the number of parallel fetches. And to avoid redundant file downloads, remember the downloaded metadata in a plist.

```
- (void) restoreCustomProfiles
{
    [self.client loadMetadata:@"/Mobile Profiles/Custom Profiles" withHash:hash];
}

- (void) restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata
{
    for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents) {
        NSString *path = [child.path lowercaseString];

        if (child.isDirectory) {
            [client loadMetadata:child.path withHash:hash];
        } else {
            [client loadFile:pathToDownload intoPath:[
                                self.directory stringByAppendingString:path]];
        }
    }
}

- (void) restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
{
    // successfully downloaded a file to destPath
}
```

Comment: I have several subdirectories to retrieve from, but you just gave me a good idea.

Comment: Hi, I have a folder called 'myfolder' into which I upload my files. I want to loadMetaData from that folder only. I understand we should use loadMetaData:withHash. So, I declared an NSString* object in the header file called 'myfolderhash' and initialized to myfolderhash = @"/myfolder" inside viewWillAppear and I use [self.restClient loadMetaData:@"" withHash:myfolderhash] but I don't see any files from myfolder now. Please advise.