# Problem in downloading Folder with dropbox api

Tags: iphone, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox api and tried to download folder but it is not working. I am able to download any type of file but not entire folder ..Here is my code which I used to download file

```
NSLog(@"called");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[metaArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 

    //NSString *file = @"/Photos";
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Downloaded Data/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],file];

    //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Downloaded Data",path];

    [self.restClient loadFile:file intoPath:path];

    NSLog(@"Downloaded");
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Load the directory metadata, then load the files that it references, see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383889/ios-dropboxsdk-get-remote-subdirectories-and-contents) for code.

Comment: Checked this link.but confused because I want to download folder.I am displaying metadata in table view.And this is displaying files and folders from @"/" root.I select the file to download but not working for folder.:(

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem as you are,

and the error log I got is that "local folder not exist"  even if I already create the folder by myself

I think that the "DBRestClient" is only the "single file" downloader?

"NOT" the folder sync object

now I'm trying to use the sync API to sync target folder

sync API address....

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios

---

thinking about that...if the "DBRestClient" can download whole folder files....

the sync API is useless....if you use like

```
[_restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
```

cheers!