# Way to change icon of accessory type in UITableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, accessoryview

I have table view which is showing list of files to download. When I tap the accessory button it will download the selected file. I want to change image of detail disclosure button. Is it possible....?

And If I use  Button with image in accessory view. Is there any table delegate method for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer2: You can make your own method and call that in that case.

```
int row=indexPath.row;

UIButton *trackImageOnMap=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420, 9, 40, 50)];
[trackImageOnMap setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"track_map_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
int iId=[[self.imageId objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
NSLog(@"iId=%d",iId);
[trackImageOnMap setTag:iId];
[trackImageOnMap addTarget:self action:@selector(trackImageOnMapButtonTouched:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[trackImageOnMap setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
//[cell setAccessoryView:trackImageOnMap];
[cell addSubview:trackImageOnMap];
```

Comment: NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[metaArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];   how can I get indexpath.row of array

Comment: You don't need to have, make that tag of your button while you are setting that button on that cell. And then the tag of that button will be your index path.:)

Comment: button.tag = cell.indexPath is giving error request for member indexpath is something not a structure or union

Comment: @Pallavi: first take cell.indexPath.row in an int variable,consider the updates in Answer,

Comment: It is ok.But in button method I have to pass name of file which is stored in metaArray.. then I have to use like NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[metaArray objectAtindex: button.tag]] or not?

Comment: I take your code and button is not showing. I used my own code also but dont know what's prob

Comment: button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 
 [button setTitle:@"Select" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button setFrame: CGRectMake( 110.0f, 3.0f, 60.0f, 30.0f)];
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapSelectButtonForDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 
 [cell.accessoryView addSubview:button ];

Comment: @pallavi: try this, [cell addSubview:button ];

Comment: But it would have hided other content for sure.. ;)

Comment: ya..but I set its x coordinate and cell.accssoryview = button is working perfect

Comment: Go to link if u can help me with this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197289/how-to-implement-horizontal-and-vertical-scroll-in-box2d-world-properly

Comment: ok.If you got time look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122800/problem-in-downloading-folder-with-dropbox-api

Comment: I saw your link but I didn't use horizontal scroll view.But  I will search about this and if found any thing will tell you surely

Comment: it's not about scroll view, it's about scrolling in box2d world.

Comment: button.tag = indexPath.row is crashing

Answer (score 4):

You could create a UIImageView and assign it to the UITableViewCell's accessoryView.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accessoryIcon"]] autorelease];
cell.accessoryView = imageView;
```

If you want a button for the accessoryView it's basically the same:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.tag = cell.indexPath;
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

Comment: And can I use NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[metaArray button.tag]]???

Comment: button.tag = cell.indexPath is giving error request for member indexpath is something not a structure or union

Comment: button.tag = indexPath.row is crashing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a default type, you can overwrite UITableViewCell and use the following code:

```
- (void)setAccessoryType:(UITableViewCellAccessoryType)accessoryType
{
    if (accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator)
    {
        self.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourNewImage.png"]] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setAccessoryType:accessoryType];
    }
}
```